# Is it possible to create a shell script used as soft link?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, symlink

I just do not know if there is a way to create shell script as soft link/symbolic link?  Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by that? You can run a shell script through a symbolic link, but it has to exist somewhere.

Comment: It's no problem.  Did you try it?

Comment: @glennjackman no.. I just do not know if it is possible..

Comment: @Politank-Z  I just want to create a shell script to return a file name, and I can run that file or edit that file.  I am not sure if it is possible..

Comment: I am sorry I did not make it clear.  I actually want to have a shell script (shell_script) which can return a file (i.e. the latest file in a directory).  In this way, when I do "vi shell_script", it can open the file I want...

Answer (score 1):

Type this in terminal:

```
ln -s /path/to/shell/script/to/be/linked /path/to/shell/script/soft/link
```

Example: **ln -s /usr/local/script1.sh /usr/scripts/**

This command will create a soft link for `script1.sh` in folder `/usr/scripts`

> **NOTE: Now you can execute the shell script using soft link itself**